# LINQ not producing expected results

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having difficulty understanding why LINQ is giving me a different result than expected.  In my code below, the first return statement always returns false.  If I pause execution and inspect the roles variable, I can see that one of the roles has a RoleID of 1, i.e. the value of RolesEnum.SystemAdmin.  Nevertheless, the count is 0.  I have also tried using Any() and it produces the same (incorrect) result.

Commenting out the first return statement, the second return statement works correctly.

Any insights or explanation into why there is a difference in the behaviours is appreciated.

Thanks.

```
var roles = GetRoleRepository(database).GetRolesForUser(userEmail);

// Why is this always false?
return (roles.Where(userRoles => userRoles.RoleID == (int)Roles.RolesEnum.SystemAdmin).Count() > 0);

bool isUserInSystemAdminRole = false;

foreach (Role role in roles)
    if (role.RoleID == (int)Roles.RolesEnum.SystemAdmin)
        isUserInSystemAdminRole = true;

// this returns the correct result
return isUserInSystemAdminRole;
```

Comment: `roles.Any(r => r.RoleID == (int) Roles.RolesEnum.SystemAdmin)` is probably the most simple expression to use. That said, if you're using ASP .NET MVC there's functions like `User.IsInRole("...")` that might be more idiomatic.

Comment: I originally was using Any(), @ta.speot.is , but changed it to Count(), just in case it was deferred execution problem.  I agree that Any() is preferable.

Comment: What do you use to access database? And what is the type of roles object. Is it IQueryable?

Comment: @evhen14 LINQ to SQL.  GetRolesForUser is in the repository layer and returns IQueryable<Role>.  Not sure if this is useful, but I added a foreach loop within GetRolesForUser that makes some changes to the roles before returning them.

Comment: @StillLearning try it out without those changes in GetRolesForUser. Will it work?

Comment: It does work.   Here's the code that I have in GetRolesForUser that I had added:  foreach (Role role in roles) if (role.RoleID >= 100) role.RoleID -= 100;

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use Entity Framework or other ORMs. They don't know how to convert this expression to SQL statements. So do the conversion beforehand like this

```
var roles = GetRoleRepository(database).GetRolesForUser(userEmail);

int roleId = (int)Roles.RolesEnum.SystemAdmin;
return (roles.Where(userRoles => userRoles.RoleID == roleId).Count() > 0);
```

Even better solution would be:

```
var roles = GetRoleRepository(database).GetRolesForUser(userEmail);

int roleId = (int)Roles.RolesEnum.SystemAdmin;
return roles.Any(userRoles => userRoles.RoleID == roleId);
```

Comment: You really should use `Any()` instead of `.Count() > 0` and even better `.Where(expression).Any();` can be simplifed in to `.Any(expression)` too.

Comment: the question is different. It's about getting wrong data, not about best practices. But I totally agree with you and will change that

Comment: Sorry, evhen14, your answer didn't work.  I still have the same incorrect behaviour that always returns false.